# Error importing data from postgres to neo4J ETL tool

Tags: postgresql, neo4j

Please i want to import data to neo4j from postgres using ETL neo4j tool but i get this error

Best Regards;

- Running ETL on Neo4j 5.3.0 - ENTERPRISE
- Direct driver instance 1911155630 created for server address localhost:7687
- Starting reading metadataMapping
- Creating constraints on nodes
- Creating constraint for label Asg and properties (asgId)
- Creating constraint for label Asbr and properties (asbrId)
- Creating nodes with label Asg
- Creating nodes with label Asbr
- Creating relationships of type "ASG_-*TO*-_ASBR"
- Data imported with errors. Below the list of errors.
- For exception ClientException we got the following errors:
- 

### Unable to execute Query: Invalid constraint syntax, ON and ASSERT should not be used. Replace ON with FOR and ASSERT with REQUIRE. (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Asg) ASSERT n.asgId IS UNIQUE"
^

Unable to execute Query: Invalid constraint syntax, ON and ASSERT should not be used. Replace ON with FOR and ASSERT with REQUIRE. (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Asbr) ASSERT n.asbrId IS UNIQUE"
^

- Closing driver instance 1911155630
- Closing connection pool towards localhost:7687

need to know the solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably it happens because the neo4j-etl constraint handler leverage a no longer valid syntax, i.e. `"CREATE CONSTRAINT ON .. ASSERT ..."`

Actually, the syntax for neo4j 5.x should be changed to `"CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR ... REQUIRE..."`.

I created a GitHub issue for this one, which we'll resolve asap:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl/issues/93